# Unity Line Renderer Color is always black on mobile

Tags: unity-game-engine

My line renderer is always black whenever I try to build to a mobile device, where as on my editor or web player it is in red. Is there any other way to solve this without using scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem may be the material you are using in the Line renderer, maybe it's a material of Shader Model 3.0 and normally mobiles only accept 2.0. I suspect you are using a material with transparency, try changing the material to one in Mobile/Particles/ like Alpha-Blended